VIMRUNTIME points to wrong path after username change
I am pretty new to WSL2/Linux and also VIM. I decided to change my username inside WSL Ubuntu (even followed some steps that were supposed to make sure the old stuff worked with the new name) and everything seemed fine but after restarting VIM, it prints
E484: Can't open file /home/[old_username]/.local/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim

I also noticed even stuff like :help is not working correctly inside VIM either, which makes me think VIM is trying to look at the wrong path for its settings.
I already tried reinstalling VIM but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to fix this or at least make it so $VIMRUNTIME points towards the correct path? Already looked everywhere and all posts end up with people telling the user "you did x wrong" but never telling them how to fix it OR the original poster saying something like "I fixed it thanks" without telling how.
